# What is the difference between areaUnderROC in BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary and BinaryClassificationEvaluator in Spark ML?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I see areaUnderROC in both BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary and BinaryClassificationEvaluator. What is the difference between them?

If my objective is to find AUC in a hold out sample, how do I choose between BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary and BinaryClassificationEvaluator?

Note: I am able to apply both on a hold-out sample.

***Links***

*BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary*

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary

*BinaryClassificationEvaluator*

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? As well as how to actually use them?